# Quotient space and equivalence classes confusion

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

I just started studying the quotient topology and equivalence relations as well, I have a question on this example which might make me understand more in general.

The interval $[0,1]$ with equivalent classes {$0,1$} and all singletons {$x$} $\in (0,1)$

When mapping $[0,1]$ with a quotient map onto the partition defined above, why is it a circle? I understand we are 'gluing' $0$ and $1$ into a single point, but more abstractly, how can I understand this?

Thank you

Comment: Consider the map $t \to (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$.

Comment: What Ayman would like to tell you is that the map $\{x\}\mapsto (\cos 2\pi x,\sin 2\pi x)$ and $\{0,1\}\mapsto (1,0)$ is a homeomorphism from the quotient space onto the unit circle.

Comment: Is it true that a quotient map always maps an equivalent class to one point?

Comment: @cazanova Yes, exactly. The preimages of points for the quotient map are exactly the equivalence classes.